# How to create instances of a subclass from an static method of an abstract class?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a method on an abstract class to build instances of a subclass of it, only if the `props` are defined, or return an `undefined` otherwise.

I tried this:

```
abstract class ValueObject<T> {
    protected props: T;

    protected constructor(props: T) {
        this.props = props;
    }

    public static buildIfDefined<C extends ValueObject<CProps>, CProps>(props?: CProps): C | undefined {
        return props !== undefined ?
            new C.constructor(props) :
            undefined;
    }
}

interface ExampleProps {
    value: number,
}

class Example extends ValueObject<ExampleProps> {
    constructor(value: number) {
        super({value});
    }
}

function buildExampleIfValueDefined(value: number|undefined): Example|undefined {
    return Example.buildIfDefined(value);
}
```

But for the line `C.constructor(props)` I receive the following error:

```
TS2693: 'C' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Can I achieve this with a better approach?

Comment: The type system only exists at compile-time. You can't try to use it in run-time context like trying to use the `constructor` property of a generic.

Comment: I mean a subclass that implements the abstract class.

Comment: I'm reading the code and really wonder why any of this is needed. It seems that you essentially want to do a *very* simple factory method which is supposed to return an instance of the current class you are calling it from. Which only differs from a constructor by possibly returning `undefined`. Is that true? Because the current implementation attempts to allow any class that inherits from the abstract one to construct any of itself or any subtype of its parent or its subclasses or subclasses of its siblings. Which seems very iffy as a design goal.

Comment: I don't want to create that method on every subclass, but in the abstract one; and there I can't just call the constructor.

Comment: You want the static method to be inherited thus to be called from any descendant, right? So you can call `Example.buildIfDefined()` or `Foo.buildIfDefined()` or `Bar.buildIfDefined()` (assuming these classes descend from `ValueObject`).

Comment: Technically, I want to avoid to check if something is defined before calling the constructor every time, and I don't want to define specific functions for that in every subclass, so I would like to have it on the abstract to be inherit, or perhaps in a ValueObjectFactory class. But in both cases I don't know how to define the types exactly...

Comment: @dgnin - Would a standalone function for that suit your needs?

Comment: I think that yes. I tried it, but I received the same error.

Comment: @dgnin - Okay, I've added one to my answer, so you have both options -- the standalone, or the `static` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the example code:

1. The problem you asked about trying to use `C.constructor`
2. The example usage is trying to treat `ValueObject<number>` as `Example`, but `Example` is `ValueObject<{value: number;}>`.

Re your follow-up comment:

> Technically, I want to avoid to check if something is defined before calling the constructor every time, and I don't want to define specific functions for that in every subclass, so I would like to have it on the abstract to be inherit, or perhaps in a `ValueObjectFactory` class. But in both cases I don't know how to define the types exactly...

When I asked if a stand-alone function would suit, you said it would, so: You can define that function like this:

```typescript
function buildIfDefined<CProps>(
    c: new (...args: any[]) => ValueObject<CProps>,
    props?: CProps
): ValueObject<CProps> | undefined {
    if (props === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return new c(props);
}
```

It accepts the constructor to use and the props to use, or `undefined`. If the props are `undefined`, it returns `undefined`, otherwise it constructs the object with the props and returns that.

Usage:

```typescript
function buildExampleIfValueDefined(
    props?: { value: number }
): Example | undefined {
    return buildIfDefined(Example, props);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgasZBXApgPIgBW+8APACoB8CA3gFAIsIAOUA9hOTwCbsubMAC4EVANyNmrDt174BsTgDtIUXPE5QAFHOFiqASgYzWrCAAsAlmAB0+jAF5BnYVPMBfRt8YAzXBV4a1UEEFxrZD4AST8AEXw-axVFCgBhAAUhMBodMyQxFIB3BB07cuAoAHNRBGAVAE8AbQBdEyc6bDwiUl50rLccgBp8xwB+MUzsxiMxLoJiMkopwboAHwRAvkTkxVNzaz9SxwQnM82VbaSUvhMmc3MofAhcKBULq92+D1ZvR+fXu9ikg9NkjFJfMkeFA-HB8AgAKIAD2AAFs2Mh8ANhPtWAA3HAEQq4VEgfBQCHSFBoDDItEY+H4JE8S4YeY9JYQCh09GY7E5XEsZRqaCaCDaHQE7rE0nku75cxgXBsck6egIKUEBCecH5by+AJBCAhd7hSJ8HkM2LshLXRR5czjMTqzX4GVkqDamZiS2YhAbLY7G6ChBPF5vMIRKKxW1fHS+-BDVzCXXeIA)

Note that it won't let you pass `ValueObject` as the constructor directly, or any other `abstract` class, because the type signature for the constructor argument requires a public constructor.

---

Re your original question:

Re #1, `C` is just a type, not a value as the error mentions. You can fix the the error by not trying to use `C` at all, using `this` instead of `C.constructor`. In a `static` method, `this` is the constructor function the method was called on (this is just the normal behavior of `this`, it's set to the object you call the method on unless there's something in place to prevent that). So if you call `Example.buildIfDefined`, `this` during the call is `Example`.

TypeScript won't like that in your `ValueObject` class because it looks, to TypeScript, as though you're trying to instantiate an `abstract` class. We can work around that by adding our own check and then telling TypeScript not to worry about it:

```typescript
public static buildIfDefined<CProps>(
    props?: CProps
): ValueObject<CProps> | undefined {
    if (this === ValueObject) {
        throw new Error(
            "ValueObject.buildIfDefined cannot be called directly, only via a subclass"
        );
    }
    if (props === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    const ctor = this as unknown as (new (props: CProps) => ValueObject<CProps>); 
    return new ctor(props);
}
```

Usage:

```typescript
function buildExampleIfValueDefined(
    props?: { value: number; }
): Example | undefined {
    return Example.buildIfDefined(props);
    //                            ^^^^^
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgasZBXApgPIgBW+8APACoB8CA3gFAIsIAOUA9hOTwCbsubMAC4EVANyNmrDt174BsTgDtIUXPE5QAFHOFiqASgYzWrCAAsAlmAB0+jAF5BnYVPMBfaeba4QyNawCJDAEEEIILjWyHwAkgBmACL4CdYqihQAwgAKQmA0OmbmrsIA-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)

This doesn't have the automatic handling the standalone function has to prevent `abstract` constructors, so we've had to work around that with the type assertion.

Comment: I didn't realize the static method could actually be called from ValueObject itself. I think the standalone function is a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: @dgnin - Me too. :-) BTW, I've updated the answer, we don't need the `C` type parameter in the standalone function for anything, and I aligned the name of the other type parameter with the name it has `ValueObject` (that is, I used `CProps` instead of `V` for it). Happy coding!